# Finding a logic function

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Im trying to find a logic function for this circuit, is it correct?

$(AB)+(A(B!)C)+((A!)C)$

[image]

Comment: What does each symbol represent?

Comment: Yes, that is fine. It simplifies to $AB+C$.

Comment: I believe the right question would be "Im trying to find a logic circuit for this expression, is it correct?"

Comment: @LucasHenrique See symbols in [Logic gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate#Symbols).